# Intersection Observer React Hooks Why is my code Not Working?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, infinite-scroll, intersection-observer

First of all, I referred to this site for reference in practicing this function.
[enter link description here](https://dev.to/producthackers/intersection-observer-using-react-49ko)

I made a hook by referring to this site and tried to apply it to the necessary file.

Here's the code for the hook.

file Name : useElementOnScreen.js

```
import React, { useEffect, useRef, useState } from 'react';

export const useElementOnScreen = options => {
  const containerRef = useRef(null);
  const [isVisible, setIsVisible] = useState(false);

  const callbackFunction = entries => {
    const [entry] = entries;
    setIsVisible(entry.isIntersecting);
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    const observer = new IntersectionObserver(callbackFunction, options);
    if (containerRef.current) observer.observe(containerRef.current);
return () => {
      if (containerRef.current) observer.unobserve(containerRef.current);
 };
  }, [containerRef, options]);
  return [containerRef, isVisible];
};
```

The file to implement the infinite scroll function using this is as follows.

file Name : MainPageCard.jsx

```
import React, { useEffect, useState, useRef } from 'react';
import MainBigCard from '../../../../components/Card/MainBigCard';
import styled from 'styled-components';
import { Rating } from '@mui/material';
import { useElementOnScreen } from '../../../../hooks/useElementOnScreen';
function MainPageCard() {
  const [mainBigCards, setMainBigCards] = useState([]);
  const [containerRef, isVisible] = useElementOnScreen({});
useEffect(() => {
    fetch('http://localhost:3000/data/MainBigCard.json')
      .then(res => res.json())
      .then(data => {
        setMainBigCards(data);
      });
  });
return (
    <Container>
      {isVisible ? 'in ViewPort' : 'not In ViewPort'}

      <Grids>
        <Cards>
{mainBigCards.map(cards => {
            return (
              <MainBigCard
                id={cards.id}
                key={cards.id}
                imgs={cards.imgs}
                Bigtitle={cards.Bigtitle}
                SmallDescription={cards.SmallDescription}
              />
            );
          })}
        </Cards>
      </Grids>
      <div containerRef={containerRef} />
</Container>
  );
}
```

Additionally, mock data uses this.
file Name : MainBigCard.json

```
[
  {
    "id": 1,
    "imgs": "https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1520986606214-8b456906c813?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=MnwxMjA3fDB8MHxwaG90by1wYWdlfHx8fGVufDB8fHx8&auto=format&fit=crop&w=1470&q=80",
    "Bigtitle": "12",
    "SmallDescription": "001"
  },
  {
    "id": 2,
    "imgs": "https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1500313830540-7b6650a74fd0?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=MnwxMjA3fDB8MHxwaG90by1wYWdlfHx8fGVufDB8fHx8&auto=format&fit=crop&w=1470&q=80",
    "Bigtitle": "13",
    "SmallDescription": "002"
  },
  {
    "id": 3,
    "imgs": "https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1534678526012-4cad1250e6bc?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=MnwxMjA3fDB8MHxwaG90by1wYWdlfHx8fGVufDB8fHx8&auto=format&fit=crop&w=1488&q=80",
    "Bigtitle": "14",
    "SmallDescription": "002"
  },
  {
    "id": 4,
    "imgs": "https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1568829486701-056199d57b24?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=MnwxMjA3fDB8MHxwaG90by1wYWdlfHx8fGVufDB8fHx8&auto=format&fit=crop&w=1573&q=80",
    "Bigtitle": "15",
    "SmallDescription": "002"
  },
  {
    "id": 5,
    "imgs": "https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1571274780648-1a1323a752b0?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=MnwxMjA3fDB8MHxwaG90by1wYWdlfHx8fGVufDB8fHx8&auto=format&fit=crop&w=1374&q=80",
    "Bigtitle": "16",
    "SmallDescription": "002"
  },
  {
    "id": 6,
    "imgs": "https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1506760610100-1af6025cf0c7?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=MnwxMjA3fDB8MHxwaG90by1wYWdlfHx8fGVufDB8fHx8&auto=format&fit=crop&w=1472&q=80",
    "Bigtitle": "17",
    "SmallDescription": "002"
  },
  {
    "id": 7,
    "imgs": "https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1552832230-c0197dd311b5?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=MnwxMjA3fDB8MHxwaG90by1wYWdlfHx8fGVufDB8fHx8&auto=format&fit=crop&w=1396&q=80",
    "Bigtitle": "18",
    "SmallDescription": "002"
  },
  {
    "id": 8,
    "imgs": "https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1498307833015-e7b400441eb8?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=MnwxMjA3fDB8MHxwaG90by1wYWdlfHx8fGVufDB8fHx8&auto=format&fit=crop&w=2456&q=80",
    "Bigtitle": "19",
    "SmallDescription": "002"
  }
]
```

I wanted to implement the infinite scroll function, but the function did not work, so I checked console.log.

- console.log(containerRef) > {current : null}
- console.log(isVisible); > false

I found that containerRef must be at the bottom of the code to implement the infinite scroll function in the map part and tried.

However, the infinite scroll function did not work on the map, and I think the function is not working because MainPageCard.jsx did not apply it properly.

I want to hear other people's opinions on which part of these files is not added and the desired function does not work.

Comment: That hook code is buggy – it doesn't unobserve/reobserve the element when the ref changes.

Comment: You might want to grab e.g. [`useIntersection` from react-use](https://github.com/streamich/react-use/blob/master/src/useIntersection.ts) instead.